# Get custom category ID of current custom post within the loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am having extreme difficulties retrieving the name (or the ID) of the current category of the custom post being viewed (within the loop).

The current category name is "school" and it is a subcategory of the custom category called "category_news"

I am trying the following, but it returns empty.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'category_news' );
if ( $terms != null ){
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        print $term->slug ;
        unset($term);
    }
}
```

Comment: category_news is your taxonomy?

Comment: yes indeed it is the taxonomy name - created with CPT UI plugin, it also has 3 subcategories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );
```

second parameter should be your taxonomy name instead of category name

Comment: Mmh my taxonomy name is "category_news"

Comment: I was writing it wrong, it is 'categories-news' :) thanks